# Socket.io matchmaking

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm working for a project in which i have to make a multiplayer battleship game, i've already completed most of the game logic (Angular 6 for the client and node.js + express for the server side), but i'm currently stuck on this since i'm new to socket.io, i've managed to get this down to try and connect 2 players :

```
var waitingPlayer = null;

ios.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('new user connected');
    if (waitingPlayer == null) {
        waitingPlayer = socket;
        waitingPlayer.emit('waitingOpponent', {
            text: "waiting for an opponent"
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Match Found');
        waitingPlayer.emit('matchFound', {
            text: "Match Found",
        });
        socket.emit('matchFound', {
            text: "Match Found"
        });
    }
});
```

If i try this it seems more than 2 users can connect together, is there a way to make some sort of lobby just between the 2 users that will be playing in the same game and then make more for the ones that will connect after? I've looked up some documentation this but couldn't find much.

Comment: Looks like you need to reset waitingPlayer.

Comment: oh ok, i didn't realize that, but then how can i exchange data just between the 2 users in game?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a good situation to use a Room with Socket IO. You can create rooms on the fly, and Socket IO basically manages them for you. So, you could create a room for each individual "Battle" or game. Put the two users in that games room. After that, you can broadcast to that room specifically. You will need to track the rooms somehow, but this should give you a starting point. Perhaps if each game that occurs has its own unique ID, the room name can be that ID. Then, you can broadcast to that specific room ID when needed.

Joining:

```
var gameId = "game_1234";
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join(gameId);
});
```

Emitting:

```
io.to(gameId).emit('some event');
```

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/